# Fles SDK Spanish localization

Tags: apache-flex, localization

I'm trying to work with a Flex project that's localized for both English and Spanish. Flex Builder is throwing the following error:

> unable to open 'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\sdks\3.2.0\frameworks\locale\es_ES'

Are there some extra files SDK files that I need to download?

As always, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the resource bundles are not available in the SDK, you'll need to create them yourself. There is a post [here](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/123) that explains how to do this.